# a bug with csv module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

```
import csv
with open('database.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['NAME'])
```

Guys, I have a csv file with the first row as a index, and in linux the code read from row['NAME'] and print only the names form colum NAME, when I run it in windows, it says:

```
C:\Users\Desktop>python py.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(row['NAME'])
KeyError: 'NAME'
```

WHY?

Comment: what's the output (of the first row) of `cat database.csv`?

Comment: does this change if you open `database.csv` as binary? `with open('database.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:`

Comment: You should change the title as it is not a bug.

Comment: saving the csv file from excel 2010 it give the error, if I use the libreoffice from linux to save it as a csv it works fine and the versions of python are: windows 2.7.10 anda suse 2.7.8.

Comment: cat database.csv
LOC;UH;PAX;DIARIA;IN;OUT;N;VALOR;ISS;TOTAL;CNPJ;RAZAO;CEP;NUMERO;COMPLEMENTO;LOGRADOURO;;
3709868;205;"RAGNARSON;RAGNAR";158;08/06/2015;11/06/2015;3;R$ 474,00;R$ 14,22;R$ 488,22;00.00.000/0000-00;SOUTH NET TURISM� BRASIL LTDA;00000-000;215;BLOCO A - 04 ANDAR;AV MARIA LEBRE AGUIAR;;ASSOCIA��O BRUIHIUH DE HIIUHIOHIJ OUHOIJES

Comment: from the file saved from libreoffice       cat database.csv
LOC,UH,PAX,DIARIA,IN,OUT,N,VALOR,ISS,TOTAL,CNPJ,RAZAO,CEP,NUMERO,COMPLEMENTO,LOGRADOURO,,,,,

Comment: There is something about the semicolons from excel 2010, how can I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by "something abou the semicolons" ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the python 2- versions, you need to open the csv with rb, i.e.:

```
with open('database.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:....
```

for reference, checkout https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html as it includes a part in the reader doc about this.

Comment: based on your comment above where you printed out the csv, where is the NAME field you are trying to look up? I'm assuming that line that ends with ;; is the index line defining columns.